# C# Rate Limiter

Tags: c#, asp.net

A flexible, fast and lightweight rate limiter that allows rate limiting of any action on a website.

Doesn't work across a scaled deployment by design, but could easily be modified to work in this way if required.  By design chose to keep it to this model.

### Example usage

If an IP address requests more than 100 page views over a 60 second period it will throw an exception:

```
var okToGo = RateLimiter.Check("Pageview",
    Code.Helpers.Common.IP.GetUserIPAddress(),
    new TimeSpan(0, 0, 60), 100);
if(!okToGo) throw new HttpException(503, "Rate limit exceeded");
```

If an IP address requests more than 100 page views over a 60 second period **or** a page view within 200ms of the last page view it will throw an exception:

```
var okToGo = RateLimiter.Check("Pageview",
    "IP." + Code.Helpers.Common.IP.GetUserIPAddress(),
    new TimeSpan(0, 0, 60), 100,
    new TimeSpam(0, 0, 0, 200);
if(!okToGo) throw new HttpException(503, "Rate limit exceeded");
```

If a user sends more than 10 PM's in an hour, or a PM within 5 seconds of their last send:

```
var okToGo = RateLimiter.Check("SendPM",
    "User." + User.ID,
    new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0), 10,
    new TimeSpam(0, 0, 5);
if(!okToGo) throw new HttpException(503, "Rate limit exceeded");
```

### Implementation

```
public class RateLimiter
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Perform a rate limit check
    /// Copyright (c) 2016 Scirra Ltd
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="actionName">Name of the action (eg "PageView", or "SendPM")</param>
    /// <param name="requestIdentifier">Unique identifier for request, eg IP address or user ID</param>
    /// <param name="period">A specified time period in which no more than maxActionsInPeriod can be performed</param>
    /// <param name="maxActionsInPeriod">Max number of actions in given period</param>
    /// <param name="minTimeBetweenActions">Optional, minimum time between actions.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static bool Check(string actionName, string requestIdentifier, TimeSpan period, int maxActionsInPeriod, TimeSpan? minTimeBetweenActions = null)
    {
        var limiter = GetRateLimiter(actionName, requestIdentifier, period, maxActionsInPeriod, minTimeBetweenActions);
        if (limiter.CanPerformAction())
        {
            limiter.PerformAction();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private int ActionsInPeriod { get; set; }
    private int MaxActionsInPeriod { get; set; }
    private DateTime LastAction { get; set; }
    private TimeSpan MinTimeBetweenActions { get; set; }

    private RateLimiter(int maxActionsInPeriod, TimeSpan? minTimeBetweenActions = null)
    {
        ActionsInPeriod = 0;
        LastAction = DateTime.MinValue;

        MaxActionsInPeriod = maxActionsInPeriod;

        if (minTimeBetweenActions == null) MinTimeBetweenActions = new TimeSpan(0);
        else MinTimeBetweenActions = minTimeBetweenActions.Value;
    }

    private void PerformAction()
    {
        ActionsInPeriod++;
        LastAction = DateTime.Now;
    }
    private bool CanPerformAction()
    {
        if (ActionsInPeriod >= MaxActionsInPeriod) return false;
        if (LastAction.Add(MinTimeBetweenActions) > DateTime.Now) return false;
        return true;
    }

    private static RateLimiter GetRateLimiter(string actionName, string requestIdentifier, TimeSpan period, int maxActionsInPeriod, TimeSpan? minTimeBetweenActions = null)
    {
        var cache = Caching.Controllers.LocalCacheController.Cache;
        var cacheKey = GetRateLimiterCacheKey(actionName, requestIdentifier);

        var limiter = cache[cacheKey];
        if (limiter != null) return (RateLimiter)limiter;

        var newLimiter = new RateLimiter(maxActionsInPeriod, minTimeBetweenActions);
        cache.Add(
            cacheKey, newLimiter, null, 
            DateTime.Now.Add(period), 
            Cache.NoSlidingExpiration,
            CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable, null);

        return (RateLimiter)cache[cacheKey];
    }

    private static string GetRateLimiterCacheKey(string actionName, string requestIdentifier)
    {
        return "RateLimiter." + actionName + "." + requestIdentifier;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you need high resolution rate limiter (with or without smoothing) I'd recommend porting https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/util/concurrent/RateLimiter.java from java (there are approx 3 files and not much code).

Comment: https://github.com/sergii-sakharov/Guava.RateLimiter

Comment: This code doesn't use thread-safe methods, limiting it to single-threaded use.  Was this intentional, or would you like it to be thread-safe?

Answer (score 1):

To me it looks like ActionsInPeriod >= MaxActionsInPeriod is flawed.
If there is any action in the period you get a `ActionsInPeriod++;`
So expired actions could still be in that ++.
But I may be mistaken.

I think a proxy server would be seen as a single user.

Comment: The Check() Method has the conditional that checks CanPerformAction() returns true; then PerformAction(). Therefore, ActionsInPeriod++ doesn't appear to get hit, when PerformAction() returns false.